# Java parsing strings Error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

Why do I get an exception error when trying to run this program? What does it mean and how can I fix it? Is it because I am using `nextline`? I get no error when running this in IntelliJ but when I run it in Zybooks (online coding lessons with assignments) I get the error.

My error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
at ParseStrings.main(ParseStrings.java:40)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userInput = "";

        System.out.println("Enter input string:");
        userInput = scnr.nextLine();

        while (!userInput.equals("q")) {

            while (userInput.contains(",") == false) {
                System.out.println("Error: No comma in string");
                System.out.println("Enter input string:");
                userInput = scnr.nextLine();
            }

            String[] myArray = userInput.split(",");

            System.out.println("First word: " + myArray[0]);
            System.out.println("Second word: " + myArray[1]);

            //get the next input
            System.out.println("Enter input string:");
            userInput = scnr.nextLine();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to ensure that there is a next line with `hasNextLine()`

Comment: Ok I am confused, where would I check if there is a nextLine

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you assign a value to userInput variable so you aren't be able to call it again in loop while so you need call it from scanner, let me add this example:

```
   while (!(userInput = scnr.nextLine()).equals("q")) {
         ....
   }
```

Comment: Wait the problem is with my loop when checking if q has been entered? This is the solution?? I don't understand. Why does intellij work but not Zybooks IDE..

Comment: really? so do you have issues on Zybooks IDE?

Comment: Yes I am not sure why but I am able to run it just fine in my other ide.